Need explanations on a few managed document properties
I see following properties in one of the managed documents.
<dls:version xmlns:dls="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls">
  <dls:latest>true</dls:latest>
  <dls:created>2024-05-09T09:12:53.721004Z</dls:created>
  <dls:author>11860319182165115804</dls:author>
  <dls:external-security-id>0</dls:external-security-id>
  <dls:external-user-name>
  </dls:external-user-name>
  <dls:annotation>
  </dls:annotation>
  <dls:deleted>false</dls:deleted>
</dls:version>

I am interested in knowing more about the dls:external-security-id and dls:external-user-name properties, however I couldn't find anything about them in the MarkLogic documentation on DLS.
Can someone please point me to the documentation or explain these properties?

I believe that they are internal constructs used to track the dls:author and handle scenarios in which External Authentication is used and the logged in user is not a local Security DB user.
You can see how it resolves and applies the values when creating/updating the dls:version properties in the /MarkLogic/Modules/MarkLogic/dls.xqy module:
declare private variable $current-user as xs:string:= xdmp:get-current-user(); 
 
declare private variable $current-user-id as xs:unsignedLong := xdmp:get-current-userid();

declare private variable $ext-sec := xdmp:user-external-security($current-user-id);

declare private variable $ext-id as xs:unsignedLong := if (fn:empty($ext-sec)) then 0 
  else data($ext-sec/extuser:external-security-id);

declare private variable $ext-user-name as xs:string := if (fn:empty($ext-sec)) then ""
  else data($ext-sec/extuser:user-name);

If you are not using external authentication, then dls:external-security-id will be 0. This is similar to how an appserver modules database ID will be 0 when it is configured to use the filesystem instead of a modules database.

Thank you for your response, Mads Hansen. I am using external authentication and authorization using OAuth 2.0 with Amazon Cognito. The dls-author property value is the id of the temporary MarkLogic user created for the external user in this case, so it should have been set as the value of dls:external-security-id property. What could be wrong here?

If you plug in the username of the external user for xdmp:user(), do you get that id 11860319182165115804? And what is returned if you use the ID with xdmp:user-external-security($id)?

I get the error SEC-USERDNE: ....... -- User does not exist: user-name = ...... when I pass username of the external user to xdmp:user(). With the same ID, I get nothing (empty-sequence) on using xdmp:user-external-security().
